# Bootstrap dropdown not working on include header php

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two pages home.php and header.php now the header file has the the top navigation bar that is to be included in the home.php page.I used a bootstrap drop down in header.php and it is working fine but when I am including header.php in home.php the nav bar is appearing perfect but the dropdown is not working so please help.Here are my codes 
header.php

```html
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 $user=$_SESSION['user'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/icon/logo.ico">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<?php
require_once("dbconnect.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='{$user}'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$name=ucfirst($row[1]);
?>
 <!--Navigation bar-->
 <div class="navi">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-brand">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rankethon</div>
    <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
   <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for friends.." size="50" id="query" name="search" value="">
                   <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                  </div>
              </div>
   </form>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span><b> Home</b></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span><?php echo "<b>$name</b>";?></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags" aria-hidden="true"></span><b> Noifications</b></a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
     <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <b>Account</b>
     <span class="caret"></span>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
     <li><a href="#" style="text-align:center"><b>Settings</b></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" style="text-align:center"><b>About Us</b></a></li>
     <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
     <li><a href="logout.php" style="text-align:center"><strong>Logout</strong></a></li>
     </ul>
     </a>
     </li>
  </div>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

home.php

```html
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
if(!(isset($_SESSION['user'])))
{
 header('location:logout.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/icon/logo.ico">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script> $(document).ready(function () { $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); }); </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("header.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you markup is invalid, because you embed the html tag two times.

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: Couldn't get you can u please elaborate a bit